# Android monkey testing

Tags: android, stress-testing, monkey

Iam testing my Android Application using monkey. So, i have used the following command...

```
adb shell monkey -p mypackage_name -v 500
```

I got the meaning of this command and its working fine but at last iam getting the feedback as follows

```
 Events injected: 22000
:Sending rotation degree=0, persist=false
:Dropped: keys=15 pointers=126 trackballs=0 flips=0 rotations=0
## Network stats: elapsed time=241946ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 241946ms not connected)
```

Please can anyone help me out in understanding these four lines...?

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Monkeys:

> The UI/Application Exerciser Monkey, usually called "monkey", is a
>   command-line tool that **sends pseudo-random streams of keystrokes,
>   touches, and gestures to a device**. You run it with the Android Debug
>   Bridge (adb) tool. You use it to stress-test your application and
>   report back errors that are encountered. You can repeat a stream of
>   events by running the tool each time with the same random number seed.

```
Events injected: 22000
:Sending rotation degree=0, persist=false
:Dropped: keys=15 pointers=126 trackballs=0 flips=0 rotations=0
```

Means 22000 event injected (Button presses, pointers, etc), 15 key presses and 126 pointer events of them where not handled by your app.